# Feature detection within a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to add something like Modernizr into your own plugin? I'd like to feature test for certain CSS3 properties without reinventing an already fantastic wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make Modernizr a pre-requisite for your plugin. Some plugins require the jQuery cookie plugin, for example, to operate correctly. This is just a different form of this situation.

Comment: So if it is included before my own plugin I can just call those functions within mine? [first time writing a plugin...]

Comment: Yup. That's all that's required. :)